# Is there any risk of injection in PHP's mail() function?

Tags: php, email, code-injection

I am wondering if there is any potential security risk from the following code. I use this on my blog whenever a user submits a comment, it will send me a text message:

```
mail('cellnumber@messaging.sprintpcs.com', '',
     "Comment posted by $name: $comment",
     "From: comments@example.com");
```

Where `$name` and `$comment` are user-entered values that haven't really been sanitized in any way. Is there any possibility that a user could do anything malicious here? The [mail()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) documentation doesn't say anything about this, but it just feels wrong to stick user-entered values directly into a string. Is there any real risk or am I just being paranoid?

Comment: I don't think anything malicious can be done however you should probably limit the length of some of the variables just so you don't piss people off.

Comment: As a side note, you quote `cellnumber`, so I assume you are using a mail-to-SMS service. If you get charged for those messages from some point, maybe somebody could bomb you with 1000s of comments and cause some damage.

Comment: Nice system you have there. I can't send sms via mail to my phone :(

Comment: @Pekka: my blog is pretty low-traffic, and Akismet pretty much blocks all spam. someone would have to be pretty determined to annoy me to spam me with thousands of comments. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as all user-stuff i's kept in the mail **body**, then there is no risk of injection.

However, as soon as a user can affect mail headers, then they can inject extra headers and do things like use it to spam arbitrary e-mail addresses or include a completely different message - including attachments.

If you check for newlines in the parts that affect the headers, and reject if it appears, then that should be enough. The SMTP standard uses CRLF to separate the header lines, but AFAIK, many Unix-based servers want you to only use LF (because that's the native line separator on those systems). The mail relayer then converts it when sending it further upstream.

Comment: Seconded. There is no direct risk here because everything's in the body but it's important to keep in mind that headers are vulnerable.

Answer (score 3):

Be aware of the newline character inside the name. Two consequent (erm.. pardon my English, two newlines one after another) newlines mean "end of headers" in SMTP.

Also, the sequence `\n.\n' (empty line with only a period) means "end of message".

EDIT: Yes, there is a risk of spammers! What if the $name actually contains:

```
 someonesName
 CC: spamsubject@domain.com; anotherspamsubject@domain.com
```

(i.e. something to inject more headers)?

EDIT2: didn't notice that "name" and "comment" were both in the body part of the message. Then my idea about spammers is not valid.

Comment: adding a CC header in there won't actually cause the email to be delivered to those addresses, it's the envelope address that's used to determine that. But Reply-to: headers could be added and probably Content-type: and then a mime body containing a virus...! I think you need to check that the name and comment fields are suitable

Comment: @naivists: I just tried this and the `\n.\n` doesn't seem to be a problem, i got all three "test" lines in the message: `mail('cellnumber@messaging.sprintpcs.com', '', "test message: test1\n.\ntest2\n\n.\n\ntest3", "From: comments@example.com");`

Comment: also, i think you meant "consecutive" :)

Answer (score 2):

PHP is full of unsafe stuff, but I'm not sure there's a lot of risk here.

Certainly a too-long comment could overflow whatever limit you might have on message size. That probably won't hurt you.

PHP's `$XXX` syntax expands the string, but doesn't do any further evaluation of the `XXX` does it? If `$XXX` worked like some kind of `eval()`, you'd be in for a world of remote code execution, but I don't think that's the case.

If this is inwardly doing SMTP, then a `.` on one line followed by a blank line would signal the end of a mail, and theoretically an attacker could follow that up with more text in successive lines to hijack your mailer to mail some other message to someone else. That's if PHP doesn't recognize and escape such a string in the first place. This is something I'd look into.

Comment: no it doesn't do any eval. just years of working with sql has made me nervous, since there is always a risk of SQL injection in that case